# Microsoft Update - list of supported software

Tags: windows-update

Is there a list of software packages that are supported for provisioning via Microsoft Update (Windows Update with the "Give me updates for Microsoft products..." option)?

I have done some searching, but can't find anything. All that I have seen are some pages indicating how [to turn it on](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/901037), but nothing indicating what's supported for update.

[image: Windows Update settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Update Catalog is available here, and seems to include a list of all products that can be provisioned via Windows Update:

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Home.aspx

Comment: FYI, You must use Internet Explorer when visiting that page.